# display questions based on user type MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I have two collections from one questions for admin comes and from other questions for user comes.
I am unable to show the questions in React using redux store.

```
store/action

import { QUESTIONS } from '../../constants/actionTypes';
import * as api from '../../services/api';
import * as paths from '../../constants/apiPaths';


const TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 60;


export const fetcQuestions = (router) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const user = await api.get(paths.FETCH_USER);
    const userType = user.type;
    console.log(userType + "userType");
    if((userType === "Student") || (userType === "STUDENT"))
    {
    const {questions, assessment, options} = await api.get(paths.FETCH_QUESTIONS);
    console.log(api.get(paths.FETCH_QUESTIONS) + "Question path");
    dispatch({ type: QUESTIONS, questions, assessment, options });
    if(assessment.responded === TOTAL_QUESTIONS) {
      router.push('/advice');
    }
    }
    else
    if((userType === "Admin") || (userType === "ADMIN"))
    {
      console.log(userType + "type of user");
      const {questions, assessment, options} = await api.get(paths.FETCH_QUESTIONS);
    console.log(api.get(paths.FETCH_QUESTIONS) + "Question path");
    dispatch({ type: QUESTIONS, questions, assessment, options });
    if(assessment.responded === TOTAL_QUESTIONS) {
      console.log("thank you");
    }
    }
   
  } catch (error) {          
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const postAssessment = (data, router) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const {questions, assessment, options} = await api.post(paths.POST_ASSESSMENT, data);
    console.log(paths.POST_ASSESSMENT + "assessment");
    dispatch({ type: QUESTIONS, questions, assessment, options });
    if(assessment.responded === TOTAL_QUESTIONS) {
    console.log("Thank you");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

please help me looking out whats wrong I am doing here. Thank You.

Reducer:

```
import * as actionType from '../../constants/actionTypes';

const assessmentReducer = (state = { questions: null, assessment: null, options: null }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.QUESTIONS:
      return { ...state, questions: action?.questions, assessment: action?.assessment, options: action?.options, loading: false, errors: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default assessmentReducer;
```

NodeJS controller:

```
const TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 120;


export const fetchQuestions = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await db.findOne('USER', { _id: req.userId});
    console.log(user + "user data");
    let answerdQuestions = [];
    let nextQuestions;
    let assessment;
    if (user.assessment) {
      assessment = await db.findOne('ASSESSMENT', { user: req.userId });
      answerdQuestions = assessment.responses.map(response => response.number)
    }
    nextQuestions = getNextQuestions(answerdQuestions);
    if ((user.type === "STUDENT") || (user.type === "student")) {
      console.log(user.type + "type");
    const questions = await db.find('QUESTIONG', { number: { $in: nextQuestions } });
    console.log(questions.number + "quesstudent");
    res.status(200).json({ questions, assessment: { id: assessment?._id, responded: answerdQuestions.length }, options: options });
    return answerdQuestions;
    }
    else {
      console.log(user.type + "typegh");
    const questions = await db.find('QUESTION', {number: { $in: nextQuestions }});
    console.log(questions.question + "quesdata");
    res.status(200).json({ questions, assessment: { id: assessment?._id, responded: answerdQuestions.length }, options: options });
    return answerdQuestions;
    }
  
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};

export const postResponses = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let responses = req.body.responses;
    let assessmentId = req.body.id;
    responses = responses.map(response => {
      return {
        score: Number(response.value),
        number: response.number,
        category: response.category,
        question: response._id
      }
    });

    const user = await db.findOne('USER', {_id: req.userId});
      console.log( user.type + "typeofuser");
    let assessment = await db.findOne('ASSESSMENT', { _id: assessmentId });
    if (assessment?.responses.length === TOTAL_QUESTIONS) {
      res.status(200).json("completed");
    }
    if (!assessment) {
      // 
      let response = {
        user: req.userId,
        responses: responses,
        responded: responses.length
      }
      assessment = await db.create('ASSESSMENT', response);
      await db.findOneAndUpdate('USER', { _id: req.userId }, { assessment: assessment._id });
      
  
    } else {
      assessment = await db.findOneAndUpdate('ASSESSMENT', { _id: assessment._id }, { $push: { responses: { $each: responses } } });
    }
    let answerdQuestions = assessment.responses.map(response => response.number);
    const nextQuestions = getNextQuestions(answerdQuestions);
    if (answerdQuestions.length === TOTAL_QUESTIONS) {
      console.log("You win");
      ]
     
   }
  if((user.type === "STUDENT") || (user.type==="student") ){
    console.log("type" + user.type);
    const questions = await db.find('QUESTIONG', { number: { $in: nextQuestions } });
    res.status(200).json({ questions, assessment: { id: assessment?._id, responded: answerdQuestions.length }, options: options });
  } else
  {
    console.log(user.type + "typeg");
    const questions = await db.find('QUESTION', { number: { $in: nextQuestions } });
    res.status(200).json({ questions, assessment: { id: assessment?._id, responded: answerdQuestions.length }, options: options });
 
  }
  
}catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};

//export default fetchQuestions;
```

I have added reducer and NodeJS controller also, Based on user type the questions are to be shown. Please help. If type is student then the questions are not getting displayed else condition the questions are getting displayed

Comment: @Tom please have a look

Comment: Hey there ok so what looks like a potential bug is the way in which the payload data is bind passed to the dispatched action as dispatch({ type: Type, questions, assessment, options })

can you show me the reducer of how this state is being handled and how the data parameters are being used then I will be able to give more context on what could be the reason 

But I think the way you would wand to have the dispatch action would be dispatch({ type: actionType, payload: { questions, assessments, options } })

This is dependant on how you are using it in the reducer

Comment: @kodamace Hey thanks for responding, I have added the reducer and the controller also. please help.

Comment: Hey @Tanya please can you maybe console.log the action parameter coming in from  the reducer and also the data before it is passed to the action in the action creator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see is, you have mentioned wrong database when you are trying to fetch data for usertype `student`. Here is your code:

```
if (user.type === 'STUDENT' || user.type === 'student') {
  console.log(user.type + 'type');
  const questions = await db.find('QUESTIONG', { number: { $in: nextQuestions } });
```

You need to correct the database name, and everything will work fine:

```
const questions = await db.find('QUESTION', { number: { $in: nextQuestions } });
```

Hope this works!!!

Comment: is there any other mode of communication in case you are not here on stack i can reach you out. You saved me and I am just a fresher.

Comment: Visit my profile and see about section @Tanyamaheshwari

Comment: can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689809/on-selecting-radio-button-next-question-is-shown-below-react

That issue I have solved. I just have to pass userType in datas and then I was able to fetch. Thanks for helping in previous problem and that helped me solve this one. Please check above link.